# XML to CSV conversion issue

Tags: php, xml, csv

I really need some help on an issue: I'm converting an XML to CSV using a PHP script, but I only need to get certain fields in the CSV, not all of them. Is there any way to specify which fields I want to import?

This is the XML file structure:

```
<PRICES>
<PRICE>
<WIC>HDE0AAFGRBOX</WIC>
<DESCRIPTION>some text here</DESCRIPTION>
<STOCK>100</STOCK>
<MY_PRICE>219.00</MY_PRICE>
<IMAGE>some image here</image>
<EAN-CODE>some code here</EAN-CODE>
</PRICE>
</PRICES>
```

This is the script I use:

```
<?
$filexml='stock.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('stock.csv', 'w')
foreach($xml->PRICES->PRICE as $price) {
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($price),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
?>
```

I only need to get WIC, STOCK and MY_PRICE.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create an array with those properties and send it to `fputcsv()` instead of `get_object_vars()`:

```
$filexml='stock.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
  $f = fopen('stock.csv', 'w');
  foreach($xml->PRICES->PRICE as $price) {
    // Array of just the components you need...
    $values = array("WIC" => $price->WIC, "STOCK" => $price->STOCK, "MY_PRICE" => $price->MY_PRICE);
    fputcsv($f, $values,',','"');
  }
  fclose($f);
}
```

Note: It may be necessary to cast these values as strings. I can't remember for certain without testing:

```
$values = array(
   "WIC" => (string)$price->WIC, 
   "STOCK" => (string)$price->STOCK, 
   "MY_PRICE" => (string)$price->MY_PRICE
);
```