# XML to CSV Conversion using Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, xml-parsing

I am looking for some help trying to convert XML retrieved from Amazon Product API to convert it into CSV(Comma Separated Value) format.

I found a similar topic here: [XML to CSV conversion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241783/xml-to-csv-conversion-issue) but it uses PHP, and I want to use javascript instead.

Here is a sample of what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
  <OperationRequest>
    <RequestId>1k75f474-85ff-464a-al93-659ol460caee</RequestId>
    <Arguments>
      <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemLookup" />
      <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService" />
      <Argument Name="Signature" Value="lImNXr6R4c2t376ghMnMmjUPR4eY6755XzH41pXGH0P=" />
      <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="oiuig-20" />
      <Argument Name="ItemId" Value="B007EHI1DK" />
      <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VA" />
      <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2013-01-04T05:23:20Z" />
      <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="Large" />
    </Arguments>
    <RequestProcessingTime>0.0359500000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
  </OperationRequest>
  <Items>
    <Request>
      <IsValid>True</IsValid>
      <ItemLookupRequest>
        <IdType>ASIN</IdType>
        <ItemId>B007EHI1DK</ItemId>
        <ResponseGroup>Large</ResponseGroup>
        <VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
      </ItemLookupRequest>
    </Request>
    <Item>
      <ASIN>B007EHI1DK</ASIN>
      <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.com/Panasonic-TY-ER3D4MU-Active-Shutter-Eyewear/dp/B007EHI1DK%3FSubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</DetailPageURL>
      <ItemLinks>
        <ItemLink>
          <Description>Technical Details</Description>
          <URL>http://www.amazon.com/Panasonic-TY-ER3D4MU-Active-Shutter-Eyewear/dp/tech-data/B007EHI1DK%3FSubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</URL>
        </ItemLink>
        <ItemLink>
          <Description>Add To Baby Registry</Description>
          <URL>http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB007EHI1DK%26SubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</URL>
        </ItemLink>
        <ItemLink>
          <Description>Add To Wedding Registry</Description>
          <URL>http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB007EHI1DK%26SubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</URL>
        </ItemLink>
        <ItemLink>
          <Description>Add To Wishlist</Description>
          <URL>http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB007EHI1DK%26SubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</URL>
        </ItemLink>
        <ItemLink>
          <Description>Tell A Friend</Description>
          <URL>http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/B007EHI1DK%3FSubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</URL>
        </ItemLink>
        <ItemLink>
          <Description>All Customer Reviews</Description>
          <URL>http://www.amazon.com/review/product/B007EHI1DK%3FSubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</URL>
        </ItemLink>
        <ItemLink>
          <Description>All Offers</Description>
          <URL>http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B007EHI1DK%3FSubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</URL>
        </ItemLink>
      </ItemLinks>
      <SmallImage>
        <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
        <Height Units="pixels">50</Height>
        <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
      </SmallImage>
      <MediumImage>
        <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
        <Height Units="pixels">107</Height>
        <Width Units="pixels">160</Width>
      </MediumImage>
      <LargeImage>
        <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL.jpg</URL>
        <Height Units="pixels">333</Height>
        <Width Units="pixels">500</Width>
      </LargeImage>
      <ImageSets>
        <ImageSet Category="primary">
          <SwatchImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL._SL30_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">20</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">30</Width>
          </SwatchImage>
          <SmallImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">50</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
          </SmallImage>
          <ThumbnailImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">50</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
          </ThumbnailImage>
          <TinyImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL._SL110_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">73</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">110</Width>
          </TinyImage>
          <MediumImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">107</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">160</Width>
          </MediumImage>
          <LargeImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31pKDguukTL.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">333</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">500</Width>
          </LargeImage>
        </ImageSet>
        <ImageSet Category="variant">
          <SwatchImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31dSwH5PnjL._SL30_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">20</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">30</Width>
          </SwatchImage>
          <SmallImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31dSwH5PnjL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">50</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
          </SmallImage>
          <ThumbnailImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31dSwH5PnjL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">50</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
          </ThumbnailImage>
          <TinyImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31dSwH5PnjL._SL110_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">73</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">110</Width>
          </TinyImage>
          <MediumImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31dSwH5PnjL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">107</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">160</Width>
          </MediumImage>
          <LargeImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31dSwH5PnjL.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">333</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">500</Width>
          </LargeImage>
        </ImageSet>
        <ImageSet Category="variant">
          <SwatchImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31irEbzxdgL._SL30_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">20</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">30</Width>
          </SwatchImage>
          <SmallImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31irEbzxdgL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">50</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
          </SmallImage>
          <ThumbnailImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31irEbzxdgL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">50</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">75</Width>
          </ThumbnailImage>
          <TinyImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31irEbzxdgL._SL110_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">73</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">110</Width>
          </TinyImage>
          <MediumImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31irEbzxdgL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">107</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">160</Width>
          </MediumImage>
          <LargeImage>
            <URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31irEbzxdgL.jpg</URL>
            <Height Units="pixels">333</Height>
            <Width Units="pixels">500</Width>
          </LargeImage>
        </ImageSet>
      </ImageSets>
      <ItemAttributes>
        <Binding>Electronics</Binding>
        <Brand>Panasonic</Brand>
        <CatalogNumberList>
          <CatalogNumberListElement>TYER3D4M</CatalogNumberListElement>
          <CatalogNumberListElement>TYER3D4MU</CatalogNumberListElement>
          <CatalogNumberListElement>TY-ER3D4MU</CatalogNumberListElement>
        </CatalogNumberList>
        <Color>One Color</Color>
        <Department>Electronics</Department>
        <EAN>0885170075207</EAN>
        <EANList>
          <EANListElement>0885170075207</EANListElement>
        </EANList>
        <Feature>Lightweight Active Shutter 3D Eyewear</Feature>
        <Feature>USB Rechargeable</Feature>
        <Feature>RF Compatible</Feature>
        <IsAutographed>0</IsAutographed>
        <IsMemorabilia>0</IsMemorabilia>
        <ItemDimensions>
          <Height Units="hundredths-inches">170</Height>
          <Length Units="hundredths-inches">340</Length>
          <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">10</Weight>
          <Width Units="hundredths-inches">670</Width>
        </ItemDimensions>
        <Label>Panasonic</Label>
        <ListPrice>
          <Amount>7995</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$79.95</FormattedPrice>
        </ListPrice>
        <Manufacturer>Panasonic</Manufacturer>
        <Model>TY-ER3D4MU</Model>
        <MPN>TY-ER3D4MU</MPN>
        <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
        <PackageDimensions>
          <Height Units="hundredths-inches">240</Height>
          <Length Units="hundredths-inches">690</Length>
          <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">30</Weight>
          <Width Units="hundredths-inches">350</Width>
        </PackageDimensions>
        <PackageQuantity>1</PackageQuantity>
        <PartNumber>TY-ER3D4MU</PartNumber>
        <ProductGroup>CE</ProductGroup>
        <ProductTypeName>CONSUMER_ELECTRONICS</ProductTypeName>
        <Publisher>Panasonic</Publisher>
        <Size>One Size</Size>
        <SKU>292782</SKU>
        <Studio>Panasonic</Studio>
        <Title>Panasonic VIERA TY-ER3D4MU Active Shutter 3D Eyewear</Title>
        <UPC>885170075207</UPC>
        <UPCList>
          <UPCListElement>885170075207</UPCListElement>
        </UPCList>
      </ItemAttributes>
      <OfferSummary>
        <LowestNewPrice>
          <Amount>5400</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$54.00</FormattedPrice>
        </LowestNewPrice>
        <LowestUsedPrice>
          <Amount>4294</Amount>
          <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
          <FormattedPrice>$42.94</FormattedPrice>
        </LowestUsedPrice>
        <TotalNew>24</TotalNew>
        <TotalUsed>18</TotalUsed>
        <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
        <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
      </OfferSummary>
      <Offers>
        <TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers>
        <TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
        <MoreOffersUrl>http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B007EHI1DK%3FSubscriptionId%3DIY7F4M00OF6I7TRD3VAS%26tag%3Daztag-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007EHI1DK</MoreOffersUrl>
        <Offer>
          <OfferAttributes>
            <Condition>New</Condition>
          </OfferAttributes>
          <OfferListing>
            <OfferListingId>rkyW%2Bed7Qb8t28tJRRHkKizuk2CxNF4SI6W9XAnbXI8JX%2FJNpUY%2B8zqnnNRe3Vt2l%2B8rUMqypquQnAE66PYmf32dJeor6DifXvXKscwOqyrLwgFZORqmDg%3D%3D</OfferListingId>
            <Price>
              <Amount>5851</Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <FormattedPrice>$58.51</FormattedPrice>
            </Price>
            <AmountSaved>
              <Amount>2144</Amount>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <FormattedPrice>$21.44</FormattedPrice>
            </AmountSaved>
            <PercentageSaved>27</PercentageSaved>
            <Availability>Usually ships in 24 hours</Availability>
            <AvailabilityAttributes>
              <AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType>
              <MinimumHours>0</MinimumHours>
              <MaximumHours>0</MaximumHours>
            </AvailabilityAttributes>
            <IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>1</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
          </OfferListing>
        </Offer>
      </Offers>
      <CustomerReviews>
        <IFrameURL>http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=AKIAIBT3ANF6TOEOKXVA&amp;alinkCode=xm2&amp;asin=B007EHI1DK&amp;atag=aztag-20&amp;exp=2013-01-05T05%3A23%3A21Z&amp;v=2&amp;sig=yz1U1nT8mWjFGauK3umnsOqp9BTzWwGOAAiLCyZ%2BEPM%3D</IFrameURL>
        <HasReviews>true</HasReviews>
      </CustomerReviews>
      <EditorialReviews>
        <EditorialReview>
          <Source>Product Description</Source>
          <Content>&lt;strong&gt;3D Playback Type:&lt;/strong&gt; Active Shutter 3D Method&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Transmittance Method:&lt;/strong&gt; RF (Bluetooth)/ Full HD 3D Glasses Standard Compatible&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Battery Type: &lt;/strong&gt;Lithium-ion Polymer Rechargeable Battery&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Battery Duration:&lt;/strong&gt; Approximately 30 hours of operation for a 30-minute full battery charge (Approximately 3 hours of operation for a 2-minute battery charge)&lt;em&gt; *The battery duration will change as per the total usage time with the number of charge/discharge cycles &lt;/em&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Package Included:&lt;/strong&gt; 1 Pair of Eyewear &lt;br /&gt;Note: These glasses are only compatible with 2012 VIERA HDTVs&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;div style="text-align: left;"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Accessory Compatibility Chart&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/div&gt; &lt;img height="375" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/Cat500/Panasonic/2012/accessory_compatibility_2._V138249826_.gif" width="650" /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</Content>
          <IsLinkSuppressed>0</IsLinkSuppressed>
        </EditorialReview>
      </EditorialReviews>
      <SimilarProducts>
        <SimilarProduct>
          <ASIN>B007K9P7H0</ASIN>
          <Title>Samsung SSG-4100GB 3D Active Glasses 2012 Models - Black</Title>
        </SimilarProduct>
        <SimilarProduct>
          <ASIN>B00752VKSC</ASIN>
          <Title>Panasonic VIERA TC-P55ST50 55-Inch 1080p 600Hz Full HD 3D Plasma TV</Title>
        </SimilarProduct>
        <SimilarProduct>
          <ASIN>B00752R4PK</ASIN>
          <Title>Panasonic DMP-BDT220 Integrated Wi-Fi 3D Blu-ray DVD Player</Title>
        </SimilarProduct>
        <SimilarProduct>
          <ASIN>B00752VKFA</ASIN>
          <Title>Panasonic VIERA TC-P55GT50 55-Inch 1080p 600Hz Full HD 3D Plasma TV</Title>
        </SimilarProduct>
        <SimilarProduct>
          <ASIN>B00752VL8G</ASIN>
          <Title>Panasonic VIERA TC-P60GT50 60-Inch 1080p 600Hz Full HD 3D Plasma TV</Title>
        </SimilarProduct>
      </SimilarProducts>
      <BrowseNodes>
        <BrowseNode>
          <BrowseNodeId>3224438011</BrowseNodeId>
          <Name>3D Glasses</Name>
          <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>172532</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Audio &amp; Video Accessories</Name>
              <Ancestors>
                <BrowseNode>
                  <BrowseNodeId>281407</BrowseNodeId>
                  <Name>Accessories &amp; Supplies</Name>
                  <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                      <BrowseNodeId>493964</BrowseNodeId>
                      <Name>Categories</Name>
                      <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                      <Ancestors>
                        <BrowseNode>
                          <BrowseNodeId>172282</BrowseNodeId>
                          <Name>Electronics</Name>
                        </BrowseNode>
                      </Ancestors>
                    </BrowseNode>
                  </Ancestors>
                </BrowseNode>
              </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
          </Ancestors>
        </BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNode>
          <BrowseNodeId>1288264011</BrowseNodeId>
          <Name>All product</Name>
          <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>1267878011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Products</Name>
              <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
              <Ancestors>
                <BrowseNode>
                  <BrowseNodeId>1267877011</BrowseNodeId>
                </BrowseNode>
              </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
          </Ancestors>
        </BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNode>
          <BrowseNodeId>3545110011</BrowseNodeId>
          <Name>Home Entertainment</Name>
          <Children>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>3547652011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Blu-Ray Players</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>3547650011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>DVD Players</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>6183878011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Home Theater Projectors</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>1294446011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Televisions</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>6183893011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Television Tuners and Receivers</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
          </Children>
          <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>1294447011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Electronics</Name>
              <Ancestors>
                <BrowseNode>
                  <BrowseNodeId>1267878011</BrowseNodeId>
                  <Name>Products</Name>
                  <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                  <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                      <BrowseNodeId>1267877011</BrowseNodeId>
                    </BrowseNode>
                  </Ancestors>
                </BrowseNode>
              </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
          </Ancestors>
        </BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNode>
          <BrowseNodeId>1293319011</BrowseNodeId>
          <Name>Electronics</Name>
          <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
              <BrowseNodeId>1267879011</BrowseNodeId>
              <Name>Special Features</Name>
              <Ancestors>
                <BrowseNode>
                  <BrowseNodeId>1267877011</BrowseNodeId>
                </BrowseNode>
              </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
          </Ancestors>
        </BrowseNode>
      </BrowseNodes>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

I am trying to format this data into a CSV formated table using Javascript.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!
Praney

Comment: you need to convert the CSV into HTML table too?

Answer (score 10):

After a long investigation i found out something that may help you.

Starting from the point that reinventing the wheel is such a stupid and time consuming task, i was looking for what other good programmers have already built out there on the internet.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find out a direct converter form XML to CSV as the example you provide in PHP.

In my working example the XML have to pass from JSON first like this:

- xml2json => json2csv

I took some pieces here and there and i will add the references of where i actually took all the code snippet i use for build the demo at the end of this answer. In this way you will be able to get a nice and clean documentation that will help you to improve this tool.

Here a simple demo:

```js
function xmlTocsv() {

    var data = $("#xmlArea").val();

    var xml = "";

    if (data !== null && data.trim().length !== 0) {

        try {
            xml = $.parseXML(data);
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }

        var x2js = new X2JS();

        data = x2js.xml2json(xml);
        jsonTocsvbyjson(data);
        
    }
}

function jsonTocsvbyjson(data, returnFlag) {

    arr = [];
    flag = true;

    var header = "";
    var content = "";
    var headFlag = true;

    try {

        var type1 = typeof data;

        if (type1 != "object") {
            data = processJSON($.parseJSON(data));
        } else {
            data = processJSON(data);
        }

    } catch (e) {
        if (returnFlag === undefined || !returnFlag) {
            console.error("Error in Convert to CSV");
        } else {
            console.error("Error in Convert :" + e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    $.each(data, function(k, value) {
        if (k % 2 === 0) {
            if (headFlag) {
                if (value != "end") {
                    header += value + ",";
                } else {
                    // remove last colon from string
                    header = header.substring(0, header.length - 1);
                    headFlag = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (value != "end") {
                var temp = data[k - 1];
                if (header.search(temp) != -1) {
                    content += value + ",";
                }
            } else {
                // remove last colon from string
                content = content.substring(0, content.length - 1);
                content += "\n";
            }
        }

    });

    if (returnFlag === undefined || !returnFlag) {
        $("#csvArea").val(header + "\n" + content);
    } else {
        return (header + "\n" + content);
    }
}

function processJSON(data) {

    $.each(data, function(k, data1) {

        var type1 = typeof data1;

        if (type1 == "object") {

            flag = false;
            processJSON(data1);
            arr.push("end");
            arr.push("end");

        } else {
            arr.push(k, data1);
        }

    });
    return arr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/abdmob/x2js/master/xml2json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>XML2CSV Demo</h1>
    <button id="convertToXmlBtn" onclick="xmlTocsv()">XML => CSV</button>
  
    <div>        
        <h4>XML:</h4>
        <textarea id="xmlArea" cols="55" rows="15"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <h4>CSV:</h4>
        <textarea id="csvArea" cols="55" rows="15"></textarea>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

References:

- [XML TO CSV Converter](http://codebeautify.org/xml-to-csv-converter)
- [x2js - XML to JSON and vice versa for JavaScript](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js)

Utils:

- [Working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/WbewzQyTFIcNS0TbWFRO?p=preview)

Comment: This function not working with complex xml but else it is working for given example xml Thank you  @Stefano Saitta

Answer (score -1):

Try to use jQuery and it would be more simple - Ref Link : [Simple XML to HTML Table](http://daigo.org/2010/08/simple-xml-to-html-table-using-jquery/)

Comment: Dead link - and exactly why link-only answers are no liked on SO