# HTML code to download csv file for next day

Tags: javascript, html, csv

hi I am trying to download file from a web page using html coding .
web link =http://www.nrldc.org/WBS/injsch.aspx
it is working ok if I am downloading it for today with following code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>view injection schedule</title>
</head>

<body onload=form1.submit()>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://www.nrldc.org/wbs/injsch.aspx" id="form1">
<div>

<input type="hidden" name ="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="download" />
<input type="hidden" name ="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="filename.csv" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![cdata[
var theform = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theform) {
     theform=document.form1;
}
function __dopostback(eventtarget,eventargument) {
if (!theform.onsubmit ||(theform.onsubmit() !=false)) {
theform.__eventtarget.value=eventtarget;
theform.__eventargument.value=eventargument;
theform.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>
</html>
```

now in date field I want to select tomorrows date and then download csv . I am unable to do it. any help/suggestions pls.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will helpful for you:

[demo example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151999/xml-to-csv-conversion-using-javascript)