# Is there any way to convert XML file into CSV using KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

I am newbie to KnockoutJS. I am looking for a way to convert XML into CSV using Knockout on the same page when I click on the button. I have extensively researched on google but no luck so far.
Can anyone please guide me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Actual conversion can be done in JavaScript using other two libraries like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34668725/10563591

I really can't see how Knockout can help with actual conversion. It is meant for binding JavaScript models to views (html pages). So create model with method `xmlTocsv()`, use `data-bind='click: xmlTocsv'` on button and bind that model with page or button.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Still I am bit confused how to accomplish this. can't I use Knockout for this purpose. Can you please elaborate bit further. If possible then can you please provide an answer for this

Comment: Honestly I don't see how knockout can help. Knockout (by definition) helps to easily associate DOM elements with model data. So Knockout is not an utility library. There are of course some utility functions available, but mainly for supporting this purpose.